# Log fields are not parsing as expected using grok filter in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok

I am using below configuration and expecting it to get parse as per below fields.

below is the `pipeline.conf` file.

```
input {
    beats {
        port => "5044"
    }
}
filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY}[T ]%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND})\| %{USERNAME:exchangeId}\| %{DATA:trackingId}\| %{NUMBER:RoundTrip:int}%{SPACE}ms\| %{NUMBER:ProxyRoundTrip:int}%{SPACE}ms\| %{NUMBER:UserInfoRoundTrip:int}%{SPACE}ms\| %{DATA:Resource}\| %{DATA:subject}\| %{DATA:authmech}\| %{DATA:scopes}\| %{IPV4:Client}\| %{WORD:method}\| %{DATA:Request_URI}\| %{INT:response_code}\| %{DATA:failedRuleType}\| %{DATA:failedRuleName}\| %{DATA:APP_Name}\| %{DATA:Resource_Name}\| %{DATA:Path_Prefix}"} 
    }
    geoip {
        source => "Client"
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
    }
}
```

actual logs are like -

```
2021-06-25T08:51:38,788| ETxatokABfg2U2wVXx2ww| atid:1b9mgcaaCgpwrcgE1FLBAiF88mk| 270 ms| 212 ms| 0 ms| api.dev.only.bfco.io [] / /*:443| | OAuth| | 156.50.222.27| POST| /piie-aiip/v5/aiip/account-success-constant| 201| | | Ba API| Root Resource| /* 

2021-06-25T13:02:41,254| 3rURHHJEh936dQEBMx-6yA| atid:x6UY50zGPx2L_qZmFm251FkQDiU| 160 ms| 8 ms| 0 ms| api.dev.only.bfco.io [] / /*:443| | OAuth| | 156.50.222.27| GET| /piie-aiip/v5/aiip/account-success-constant/97e7a7b9-3e60-4508-a35b-d0a01ba902bb| 200| | | Ba API| Root Resource| /* 

2021-06-25T13:03:51,257| P0nH46kGVFnhZZ5iC6ZU1g| atid:y7UX49zBPy1P_wXnFm251FkQDiU| 39 ms| 2 ms| 0 ms| api.dev.only.bfco.io [] / /*:443| | OAuth| | 156.50.222.27| GET| /piie-aiip/v5/aiip/account-success-constant-asu| 400| | | Ba API| Root Resource| /*
```

but when checked on kibana, i am seeing message field as one field (below) and not separated into above individual fields as mentioned in pipeline.conf.

below from Expanded document - Table.

```
message         2021-06-25T13:01:03,478| XQvIx-qYtp2lP0tLcr53pQ| 
                atid:y7UX99zGPx2L_qZmFm101EkQBiU| 180 ms| 10 ms| 0 ms| api.dev.only.bfco.io 
                [] / /*:443| | OAuth| | 156.50.222.27| POST| /piie-aiip/v5/aiip/account-success- 
                constant| 201| | | Ba API| Root Resource| /*
```

I wanted to run query on one of the field (NUMBER:RoundTrip:int)

When checked above in Grok Debugger it is showing the expected results.

i.e put sample data as above one of the log line,
Used above grok Patten,
it is giving below output.

```
{
  "response_code": "201",
  "method": "POST",
  "subject": "",
  "Request_URI": "/piie-aiip/v5/aiip/account-success-constant",
  "Resource": "api.dev.only.bfco.io [] / /*:443",
  "UserInfoRoundTrip": 0,
  "APP_Name": "Ba API",
  "authmech": "OAuth",
  "Resource_Name": "Root Resource",
  "failedRuleName": "",
  "exchangeId": "XEyIx-yYtp2lP0kLcr08kP",
  "RoundTrip": 180,
  "ProxyRoundTrip": 10,
  "scopes": "",
  "Client": "156.50.222.27",
  "Path_Prefix": "",
  "failedRuleType": "",
  "trackingId": "atid:y8YX50zGPx3L_qZmg981FkEBiU"
}
```

1 Q. Can someone please advise what is wrong in pipeline.conf preventing message field to be individual fields.

2 Q. also not sure why below fields are showing as long in Index Patterns when it is passed as int.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is able to parse the above expected fields. Missed to see it.